# How to select elements that contain &nbsp; and add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to add one class to more than one  element and I wanted to do it through jQuery but I am noob and I dont know how to select those  elements with content of nsbp; . Here is the case:

```
  <ul>
       <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><b>Example</b> <br><span>Example Description</span></a></li>
       <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
       <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><b>Example</b><br><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
       <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>
       <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><b>Example</b><br><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
       <li class="line2">&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
```

Please help!

Comment: Just search `addclass in Jquery` using google.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — The question says the problem is selecting the elements, that search won't help.

Comment: what in the code are you trying to select?

Comment: All those spans with content of &nbsp;

Answer (score 7):

May be like this:

```
$("span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().match(/&nbsp;/) !== null;
}).addClass("some-class");
```

Or may be like this:

```
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
// In Unicode, [the non-breaking space] is encoded
// as U+00A0 (HTML: &#160; &nbsp;)
$("span:contains('\u00a0')").addClass("some-class");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the nodes that have those specific classes:

```
// Select all the nodes that have either the class "spacer" or the class "line2"
var elements = $('.spacer, .line2');
// Add another class
elements.addClass('newClass');
```

If you want all the nodes whose content is `&nbsp;`, then you should use the `contains` selector or a `filter`, as other answers say, but if you don't need that (or you can change the HTML so all the nodes with `&nbsp;` have an specific class) then selecting by class is more performant and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Anything like this:

```
$("elementYouWantAddClass").hasClass("yourClassCss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()=="&nbsp;") {
            $(this).addClass('css_class_name');
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$("ul li").not(':has(a)').addClass('classname');`

Please ignore the above one and try the following snippet.

```
$('span').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html().indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1;
}).addClass('yourClass');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Gy9Kd/)